# Load balance and contingency server

Tags: windows, iis, load-balancing, high-availability, arr

everyone. I'm having trouble setting up a load balancing/contingency server.

**My scenario:** I have 2 servers (Windows 2012 R2 machines) to run an application in ASP.Net/C#.

**My problem:** Would I like to switch servers, when a server shut down the other assuming its operation. I can not have both servers running because there is a service that can replicate the application actions.

**What I have tried so far:** Well, I tried to solve using ARR (Application Request Routing) in IIS, but I could not make the farm server turn the host application (happened the 502.4 error).
See also by the Windows balancing method (load balancing manager) is not possible since, you need a cluster to manage the machines, right?

*I wanted to avoid implement a switch by software from my application because I will have to keep sync data and DB too.*

What kind of solution I should seek for this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question.  Your problem statement is not clear.  Same problem with What you ave tried so far

Comment: @kheld question updated :)